# Cloud App API For Visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, azure, cloud

Is there a cloud app api available for developing on Visual Basic [2008 or 2010]

Comment: What do you mean by "Cloud App API"? It's hard to discern your meaning. Also, what are you trying to accomplish? Do you need persistence? Do you need a server that can run your code 'in the cloud'? What is your use case?

Answer (score 5):

all .NET language include C#, VB, VC++, F#, etc can use Windows Azure .NET SDK and Visual Studio

Comment: That is true, but it does depend on versions too

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean, exactly, because you will need a cloud service to run in and there is no standard API across these services.  But if you use Windows Azure there are very helpful APIs available to VB.NET and C#.

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/sdk/

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are very new to Cloud and Windows Azure. I would suggest visiting the link below and start from Level 100 to learn more about it:
http://walearningpath.cloudapp.net/

If you following Level 100 and exercise 3 you will be given a chance to write your first program using C# or VB.NET.

If you just follow the hands on lab below with VB.NET code, you will learn how to write your first Cloud Application on Windows Azure: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_introtowindowsazurelabvs2010_topic2#_Toc313609301

Answer (score 1):

As long as you stay with .Net, you can use the [basic Azure SDK](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/).

This SDK is applicable for all .Net languages, let it be C# (mostly used in examples), VB.NET (not VB6 or VBA!), F#, PowerShell, IronPython, IronRuby and even PowerBuilder (from version 12.5) or Delphi\Embarcadero (starting from Delphi Prism)

Answer (score 0):

You can develop Azure applications in VB.Net using Visual Studio with the Azure SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever language you're using, just use the web services that are available. Each of the major cloud providers that have legitimate capabilities (i.e. Windows Azure, Amazon Web Services/EC2, Rackspace) all have APIs, SDKs, etc that access their services. Anyone can connect to these elements of the services.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Azure SDK for Visual studio includes a cloud project that one uses to package a .net application so that it can be deployed on Azure.

The SDK also contains an API that provides access to Azure features (these are accessible from any platform over REST/HTTP, but the API makes them much easier to consume.)

Both support VB.net as much as they support C# and other languages.

However - the [Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee405484.aspx) only support Visual Studio 2012 and 2013. 2010 is no longer supported, can't remember if 2008 ever was.

Also - whilst, in theory, you could manually package projects that have been developed using earlier versions of VS or indeed other tools, [only version 3.5 and above of the .net framework is supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj573576.aspx) on Windows Azure which would prevent running projects from earlier versions

Answer (score 0):

Well to answer your question briefly of course there are many Cloud APIs available but the best 1 that offers more support to Visual Basic is Windows Azure in deed.

You can find this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee405487.aspx
which will help you to crate your first windows Azure project easily.

Comment: You'll need Windows Azure SDK of course to start developing windows Azure and you can find it here : [link](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/?sdk=net)